# JSX element type does not have any construct or call signatures. Typescript

Tags: typescript

In case `compose` is used there is an error   `JSX element type ‘Option’ does not have any construct or call signatures.`
'redux' version - 3.7.2

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
const { connect: fela, withTheme } = require('react-fela');

const Option = compose(
    ...[
        connect(null,
            dispatch => ({
                onClick: (name) => dispatch(setActive(name)),
            })),
        fela({
            option: ({ theme }) => ({
                ...getControlOptionColors(theme),
            }),
        }),
    ],
)(withTheme(({ label, name, onClick, styles }) => (
    <div className={styles.option} onClick={onClick.bind(this, name)}>{label}</div>
)));

export class Test extends React.PureComponent<any, any> {

    private renderOptions(options) {
        return (
            <div className={this.props.styles.options}>
                {options.map(option => (
                    <div key={option.value}>
                        <Option
                            label={option.label}
                            name={option.value}
                        />
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }


    public render() {
        const { options } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className={this.props.styles.container}>
                {this.renderOptions(options)}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Controls;
```

Without compose, Everything work fine.

```
const Element = withTheme(({ label, name, onClick, styles }) => (
        <div className={styles.option} onClick={onClick.bind(this, name)}>{label}</div>
    ))

const conponentWithConnect = connect(null,
    dispatch => ({
        onClick: (name) => dispatch(setActive(name)),
    }))(Element);

const Option = fela({
        option: ({ theme }) => ({
                    ...getControlOptionColors(theme),
        }),
    })(withConnect)
```

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the redux types

Answer (score 22):

You need to type cast the component returned by compose as React.ComponentType and it works fine. So:

```
compose(...)(SomeComponent) as React.ComponentType
```

Comment: This probably does solve the problem, but using a cast (`as`) should be considered a last resort since it overrides the type checker. If possible it is better to tighten up the types of values that are causing type checking to fail, and/or insert appropriate type guards so that TypeScript can infer the types correctly.

Answer (score 9):

An updated answer; use the generics for `compose`:

```
import React, { ComponentType, FC } from 'react';

export default compose<ComponentType>(
  withWidth,
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
  )
)(Search)
```

Comment: Thanks for that!

Comment: This should be the most upvoted answer

Comment: Thanks. One addition - If the `Search` component has props declared as `SearchProps`, then use `export default compose<ComponentType<SearchProps>>(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you are wrapping your arguments to `compose` in an array, and then destructuring the array using the spread operator (`...`).

There is no reason to do this since it is semantically equivalent to passing the arguments directly. This construction may also prevent TypeScript from inferring the type parameters for `compose` correctly.

You could rewrite your `compose` call as

```
const Option = compose(
    connect(null,
        dispatch => ({
            onClick: (name) => dispatch(setActive(name)),
        })),
    fela({
        option: ({ theme }) => ({
            ...getControlOptionColors(theme),
        }),
    }),
)(withTheme(({ label, name, onClick, styles }) => (
    <div className={styles.option} onClick={onClick.bind(this, name)}>{label}</div>
)));
```

That might solve the problem, but I can’t be sure as the snippet of code you’ve provided is not sufficiently complete for me to test it.