# Impossible to test a React component wrapped with redux compose

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, jestjs

I need to test a React component (Toto) with Jest.
This component is exported with two HOC thanks to the redux compose function.

When I try to use the Toto component in my test file (Toto.test.tsx) I have a TS2604 error (JSX element type 'Toto' does not have any construct or call signatures).

Toto.test.tsx

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import * as React from 'react';
import Toto from '../../Toto';

function setupFullRenderingComponent(options: any = {}) {
  const props = {
    toto: 'hello'
  }

  const wrapper = shallow(   
    <Toto {...props} />
  );

  return {
    props,
    wrapper
  };
}

describe('Toto', () => {
  const { wrapper } = setupFullRenderingComponent();
  console.log(wrapper);
});
```

Toto.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import WithHelp from '../../../WithHelp';

class Toto extends React.Component<
  any,
  any
> {
  public constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      total: 0
    };
  }

  // SOME STUFF

  public render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.total}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default compose(
  withRouter,
  WithHelp
)(Toto);
```

How can i fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: does this component work fine in live project?

Comment: take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701121/jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call-signatures-typescript Not sure if your and that cases are equal but there are few ideas how to make work around

Comment: Yes it is imported the same way and it is working fine live. Thank you

Comment: Thank you Skyboyer, indeed adding "as React.ComponentType" solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

You can write `export  class Toto extends ...` and then can `import {Toto} from ...` in test file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "as React.ComponentType" solved my issue. Thank you for your help