# Typescript import error with when importing a composed component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-firestore

I'm facing a weird import error when I try to import a redux `compose` component,
I can't tell what's causing it, I've installed all the latest `@types` for the the involved packages:

Error:

`JSX element type 'PostTable' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

## Parent

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CreatePost from '../postings/CreatePost';
import PostTable from '../postings/PostTable';

export default (props: { [key: string]: any }) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <CreatePost></CreatePost>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <PostTable></PostTable> //Error occurs here
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

## Child

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';

const PostTable = (props: { [key: string]: any }) => {
  return (
    <table className="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">#</th>
          <th scope="col">First</th>
          <th scope="col">Last</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {props.posts.map((post: { [key: string]: any }) => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <th scope="row">{post.id}</th>
              <td>{post.title}</td>
              <td>{post.content}</td>
            </tr>
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: { [key: string]: any }) => {
  return {
    posts: state.firestore.ordered.posts,
  };
};

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  firestoreConnect([
    {
      collection: 'posts',
    },
  ])
)(PostTable);
```

Comment: Just curious, do you get the same error if you do `export const PostTable = ...` and then `import { PostTable } from '...'` in the parent component?

Comment: @3066d0 yeah I've tried both, they both give me the same error

Comment: Solution can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701121/jsx-element-type-does-not-have-any-construct-or-call-signatures-typescript